# Select all rows with certain year, plus all rows of affected group

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in which each hundret rows have the same id (see "chart_id" in shortened Example below).

If we consider every row with the same "chart_id" a "chart" how do I select every chart having a certain year in it with a mysql query.

For example how do I select every chart with 2009 in it (chart2 and chart3):

*edit*:
rows with id 4,5,6 and 7,8,9 should be selected if I look for 2009.

```
id   chart_id  time
1    1         2008
2    1         2008
3    1         2008

4    2         2008
5    2         2008
6    2         2009

7    3         2009
8    3         2009
9    3         2009

10   4         2010
11   4         2010
12   4         2010
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT chart_id
FROM myTable
WHERE time = 2009
```

Or, do you mean you want all the rows for that chart [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/484c7/1):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 
             FROM myTable t2 
             WHERE t2.chart_id = t1.chart_id AND t2.time = 2009)
```

Comment: > Or, do you mean you want all the rows for that chart:

Yes, I want all of them, even the ones without the 2009 inside the affected chart.
Your query didn't work for me. Either it timed out after 30secs or it gave back too few rows.

Comment: @leOm Well, then there's something else going on. Check out the fiddle, it works perfectly.

Comment: Your right! In my case time is a timestamp. I guess I have to convert "time" from timestamp to year. I tried to use YEAR('time') but I didn't where to place it correctly. Any suggestion?

Comment: Got it! I just changed t2.time into YEAR(t2.time)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a `SELECT DISTINCT chart_id WHERE year ...` would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT chart_id FROM table_name WHERE time = 2009
```